# How to determine time to first byte?

Tags: performance, firebug, timing, pagespeed

I have been reading a lot about performance lately and there are tools which can assist you in increasing speed of a web page. But I could not find any tool that can tell me what is time to first byte for my web pages. Any hint?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[WebPageTest.org](http://www.webpagetest.org/) is great but you can also use your browser dev tools to quickly check the TTFB. 
All your need is a network waterfall chart. Another method is to time your [page render yourself](http://www.phpjabbers.com/measuring-php-page-load-time-php17.html).

### Firefox

[image: Firefox Net Panel]

### Chrome

[image: Chrome Network Panel]

### Internet Explorer

[image: Internet Explorer Network Panel]

Answer (score 1):

http://www.webpagetest.org/ hosts a tool that can measure that amongst other interesting things, from different locations worldwide.